# Refer to an HTML control created in code-behind using its html identifier

Tags: html, asp.net, controls, code-behind, identifier

1) I create a panel in code-behind and specify its ID as "Panel123". The panel later receives its html ID when rendered on the html page. This ID in html will look like "ctl00_ctl00_bla_bla_bla_Panel123".

2) I create and register a javascript block in code-behind and it refers to the Panel by its ID. So in code-behind I need to retreive future html ID of the panel and embed this ID into the script.

I tried ClientID, UniqueID, ID, but all these server-side properties give only the ending part of the panel id, not the whole thing with bla_bla_bla stuff.

I also tried to put the string "<%=Panel123.ClientID%>" into the script text, but then in html it was rendered as follows (I add spaces deliberately to prevent replacing the symbols): **' & lt ; % =Panel123.ClientID%>'**. So as you see the script doesn't recognize it as a valid html ID.

How to get the entire html id in code-behind?

**CODE-BEHIND**

```
Panel123 = new Panel();
Panel123.ID = "Panel123";

...

LinkButton123.OnClientClick = "function123(this,'<%=Panel123.ClientID%>'); return false;";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution myself.

Instead of retrieving html generated ID, I add id to the control using the following construction: Panel123.Attributes.Add("id", "Panel123").

It directly sets the pure html identifier without any other server-generated "bla_bla_bla" stuff.

Comment: Do you end up with two `id` attributes that way?

Comment: I replaced Panel123.ID="Panel123" with this new approach. So I specify only one id.

Comment: I'm not talking about what you specify...I'm talking about the resulting HTML. Do you end up with two `id` attributes?

Comment: I don't think asp.net is that dumb to add its own generated id when you specify yours using absolutely proper way provided by microsoft. There is only one id in html.

Comment: Don't count on it. I've seen it add multiple `class` attributes before. When you work with .NET 3.5, you're using really old code and should strongly consider upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use inline syntax from a string created on the server like that. Instead, just concatenate it on.

```
LinkButton123.OnClientClick = "function123(this,'" + Panel123.ClientID + "'); return false;";
```

Either that, or change the [`ClientIDMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx) of the panel to `Static`. Then the ID will always be just `Panel123`.

```
Panel123 = new Panel();
Panel123.ID = "Panel123";
Panel123.ClientIDMode = "Static";
LinkButton123.OnClientClick = "function123(this,'Panel123'); return false;";
```

Comment: @Vladimir What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @Vladimir Is this a new project? Or an existing one? You should be using .NET 4 and Visual Studio 2013 at the least. Anyways, `ClientIDMode` wasn't added until .NET 4.

Comment: @Vladimir Add your panel to the `Controls` collection of something else, *then* use the `ClientID` property. Or do the easy thing and upgrade to .NET 4 and VS 2013.